# One-player game using coin with head probability $p$. Player tosses a coin and increment score if head, else decrement. Find probability of score $2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, game-theory, variance

Consider a game by a single player using a coin with head probability $p\; (0 < p < 1)$. The player starts the game with her initial score $0$, and repeats a trial (called round) in which she tosses a coin and increases her score by one if head, otherwise decreases her score by one. The game is over with her win once her score gets to $2$, while the game is over with her defeat once her score gets to $—2$. Answer the following questions.

1. For each $k=1, 2, 3$, answer the probability that she wins the game exactly at the $2k$-th round and the probability that she looses the game exactly at the $2k$-th round, respectively.
2. Answer the probability that she wins the game.
3. Answer the expectation and the variance of the number of times that she wins when she repeats the game $100$ times.
4. Let $p = 0.6$. Establish with reason whether or not the probability is higher than $1/10$ that the number of times she wins is less than $50$ when she repeats the game $100$ times.

---

Here is my attempt.

[image]

Can someone please check if the approach is correct, especially for 2 and 4 part?

Comment: Welcome. Posting image is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Since you are new contributor, the images have been converted to text for once (If you can't see text, assume that conversion process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. If possible, we would like to see your efforts on question too. Happy Learning!

Comment: For (1), it looks like you are answering only when $k=1$. What happens if $k>1$?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning (resp. losing) at the $2k^{\mathsf{th}}$ round is is $2^{k-1}p^2(p(1-p))^{k-1}$ (resp. $2^{k-1}(1-p)^2(p(1-p))^{k-1}$). This follows from a win (resp. loss) at the $2k^{\mathsf{th}}$ round consisting of two heads (resp. tails) and $k$ heads/tails pairs.

Letting $\tau_i$ be the probability of winning given that the current score is $i$, for $i\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$, we have the recurrence $\tau_i= p\tau_{i+1} + (1-p)\tau_{i-1}$, and with the boundary conditions $\tau_2=1, \tau_{-2}=0$, it follows that
$$
\tau_0 = \frac{p^2}{1-2 p+2p^2}.
$$
If the game is repeated $n$ times, then the distribution of the number of wins is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $\tau_0$, and hence has mean $\frac{np^2}{1-2 p+2p^2}$ and variance $n\left(\frac{p(1-p) }{1-2p+2p^2}\right)^2$.

If $p=3/5$ then the probability of winning less than 50 times when the game is played $100$ times is
\begin{align}
&\sum _{k=0}^{49} \left(\frac{\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2}{\frac{2}{5} 3 \left(\frac{3}{5}-1\right)+1}\right)^k \left(1-\frac{\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2}{\frac{2}{5} 3 \left(\frac{3}{5}-1\right)+1}\right)^{100-k} \binom{100}{k}\\
=& \tiny\frac{3733426269496958096470429118425665418368735163407238068404578920487073841498634546664688980706863475589120}{190718085458920964116236375748835779710674959067303165370168392262012207679844273858329666379998629245551661077}\\
&\approx0.0000195756\\
&\ll\frac1{10}.
\end{align}

Comment: I would say the probabilities of winning/losing on the $(2k)^{\text{th}}$ round are $$2^{k-1}\left(p(1-p)\right)^{k-1}p^2,2^{k-1}\left(p(1-p)\right)^{k-1}(1-p)^2$$ respectively.  For example, any one of the $2^{3-1}=4$ outcomes belong to the event of victory after exactly $6$ rounds:

$$\text{THHTHH},\text{THTHHH},\text{HTTHHH},\text{HTHTHH}$$

Note summing up $2^{k-1}\left(p(1-p)\right)^{k-1}p^2$ from $k=1$ to $\infty$ yields $\frac{p^2}{1-2p(1-p)}$ which matches your formula for $\tau_0$.

Comment: @MatthewH. Indeed, a bit of a combinatorics fail on my part. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: yes, i understand it now, really appreciate your help.